# R iteratively select and remove values from a vector

Tags: r, probability, sample

I want ot iteratively select a number of values from a vector (based on a coin-toss decision probability) and remove them from that vector, then in the next loop of iteration, I again want to select (following coin-toss) values from the remaining vector values. Until I will reach the point that my vector is empty. Following is the solution in my mind but at the end I get stuck with one non-selected value in the vector:

```
vector <- c("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8", "item9", "item10")
  for (i in 1:10) {
    #select values from the vector based on coin-toss probability, so that roughly half of the items get selected
  selected <- sample(vector, replace = F, size = length(vector)/2)
  print(slected)
  # Do some operation with slected values

  # remove the selcted values from the original vector
  vector <- vector[!vector%in%selected]
  print(vector)
  # as we are in loop this will keep happening until we are done selecting all of the elements in the vector.
  }

NOTE: I don't want to select any value twice!
```

Can anybody guide me what can be a better solution for this.

EDIT: Can there be a coin-toss based selection, where I don't give the size explicitly. For example, for every value in the vector we calculate a probability of selection and if it is higher than 0.5 then that value get selected and not otherwise.

I want to do it this way because I want to iterate over this vector 1000 of times and I expect to get different results based on different kind of selection in every iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a different solution. Notice that the most important change is the use of `ceiling` in defining the sample size.

```
x <- c("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7",
       "item8", "item9", "item10")

while(length(x) > 0) {
  selected <- sample(x, replace = FALSE, size = ceiling(length(x)/2))
  cat("selected:", selected, "\n")
  x <- x[!x %in% selected]
  cat("remaining:", x, "\n\n")
}

selected: item5 item3 item8 item10 item4 
remaining: item1 item2 item6 item7 item9 

selected: item1 item2 item9 
remaining: item6 item7 

selected: item6 
remaining: item7 

selected: item7 
remaining:
```

I also used a `while` loop instead of OP's `for` loop since that makes more sense conceptually.

---

Regarding OP's comments:

You can also try something like the following where you don't define the sample size that is being selected. Note however, that this can easily lead to some cases where no or all elements are selected, even though the probabiliy for each element is 0.5:

```
x <- c("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", 
       "item8", "item9", "item10")
while(length(x) > 0) {
  selected <- x[sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size = length(x), replace = TRUE)]
  cat("selected:", selected, "\n")
  x <- x[!x %in% selected]
  cat("remaining:", x, "\n\n")
}
```

Comment: Can there be a coin-toss based selection, where I don't give the size explicitly and based on a coin-toss decision random sample is withdrawn from the population (vector here)?

Comment: For example, for every value in the vector we calculate a probability of selection and if it is higher than 0.5 then that value get selected and not otherwise.

Comment: @Newbie, that's a different question in my opinion

Comment: I am thinking of `sample(x, replace = FALSE)` first and then fragment the shuffled vector into subvectors of size 5, 3, 1, 1 sequentially. I am not sure whether this sampling-once method is equivalent to iterative sampling.

Comment: @Newbie, I added another approach

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thank you very much for your help. I have added an EDIT to my question, may be that will make my point clear. Please let me know if your new solution will tackle the explained problem.

Comment: @Newbie, as far as I can tell, my second approach does what you asked for in the edit. For each element we sample either a TRUE or FALSE (with probabiliy = 0.5) to be selected or not.

Comment: @docendodiscimus I see.. Thanks a lot!